# NAudio used filter in MediaFoundationResampler

Tags: naudio, ms-media-foundation

Does anyone know what type of filter and order is applied when using MediaFoundationResampler to resample audio?

I looked in the sourcecode of NAudio and as far I understand the resampling happens in the MediaFoundation. On MSDN I didn't find a hint which filter is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Microsoft reveal details of the internal implementation, but there is a [quality setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819449(v=vs.85).aspx) (which NAudio exposes as `ResamplerQuality`) you can set between 1 (linear interpolation) and 60 (highest quality). It is set internally with a call to [SetHalfFilterLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819251(v=vs.85).aspx), which may provide a clue to what is going on in terms of DSP.

Comment: Ok thx. On my research, I found out that NAudio also has an resampler. called WdlResamplingSampleProvider. Maybe you could tell me something about the filters? I tried to understand the sourcecode, but unless now I didn't exactly figured out.

Comment: The wdl resampler is a c# port of the [Cockos WDL Resampler](http://www.cockos.com/wdl/) (used with permission). You could ask on their forums if you need to know the details of how it works

Comment: Thx Mark for your kind help.